# SQL Server procedure where IS NULL or parameter like give wrong result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_FIND]
(
    [UNIT1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UNIT2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UNIT3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UNIT4] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and data in that table looks like this

```
UNIT1 | UNIT2 | UNIT3 | UNIT4
a     | b     | c     | d
null  | b     | null  | null
null  | null  | c     | null
null  | null  | null  | d
a     | null  | null  | null
```

and my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A_TEST]
    @UNIT1 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @UNIT2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @UNIT3 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @UNIT4 nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        UNIT1, UNIT2, UNIT3, UNIT4
    FROM
       TEST_FIND
    WHERE
       @UNIT1 is null or UNIT1 like '%'+@UNIT1+ '%' AND
       @UNIT2 is null or UNIT2 like '%'+@UNIT2+ '%' AND
       @UNIT3 is null or UNIT3 like '%'+@UNIT3+ '%' AND
       @UNIT4 is null or UNIT4 like '%'+@UNIT4+ '%'
END
```

The problem is, when I call my procedure like this:

```
exec A_TEST 'a', null, null, null
```

the result is ok (just show from table TEST_FIND where UNIT 1 is 'a')

but when use

```
exec A_TEST null, 'b', null, null
```

the result is

```
select * from TEST_FIND
```

I don't know why, and what's the problem

Need fix this soon, help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you group your `WHERE` clauses? Like so:

```
WHERE
   ( @UNIT1 is null or UNIT1 like '%'+@UNIT1+ '%' )
   AND
   ( @UNIT2 is null or UNIT2 like '%'+@UNIT2+ '%' )
   AND
   ( @UNIT3 is null or UNIT3 like '%'+@UNIT3+ '%' )
   AND
   ( @UNIT4 is null or UNIT4 like '%'+@UNIT4+ '%' )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

use brackets in AND condition.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A_TEST]
@UNIT1 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT3 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT4 nvarchar(50) = NULL
   AS
     BEGIN
       SELECT
        UNIT1,
     UNIT2,
     UNIT3,
     UNIT4
FROM
   TEST_FIND
    WHERE
  (@UNIT1 is null or UNIT1 like '%'+@UNIT1+ '%') AND
  (@UNIT2 is null or UNIT2 like '%'+@UNIT2+ '%' )AND
  (@UNIT3 is null or UNIT3 like '%'+@UNIT3+ '%')AND
  (@UNIT4 is null or UNIT4 like '%'+@UNIT4+ '%')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply parathesis for the OR coditions as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A_TEST]
@UNIT1 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT3 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@UNIT4 nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
   UNIT1,
   UNIT2,
   UNIT3,
   UNIT4
FROM
  TEST_FIND
WHERE
   (@UNIT1 is null or UNIT1 like '%'+@UNIT1+ '%') AND
   (@UNIT2 is null or UNIT2 like '%'+@UNIT2+ '%') AND
   (@UNIT3 is null or UNIT3 like '%'+@UNIT3+ '%') AND
   (@UNIT4 is null or UNIT4 like '%'+@UNIT4+ '%')
  END
```